# Flutter shared preferences saving int value locally

Tags: flutter, dart, sharedpreferences, flutter-provider

I am building a page that the user can select a prefered profile picture to show arround the app, using `provider` package. I used `shared_preferences` to save the profile picture preferences on locally as a `int` value. For that I have added 15 SVG images to the assets folder, and user can select just only one of them for this purpose. The SVG images are renamed as `1.svg`, `2.svg`...`15.svg`, so I can access the SVG using that `int` value.

**This is the shared_preferences class that I created**

```
class ProfilePicPref {
  static const PRO_PIC_STS = 'PROFILESTATUS';

  setProfilePic(int svgNo) async {
    SharedPreferences profilePref = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    profilePref.setInt(PRO_PIC_STS, svgNo);
  }

  Future<int> getProfilePicture() async {
    SharedPreferences profilePref = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    return profilePref.getInt(PRO_PIC_STS) ?? 1;
  }
}
```

**This is the Provider class that I created**

```
class ProfilePicProvider with ChangeNotifier {
  ProfilePicPref profilePicPreferences = ProfilePicPref();
  int _svgNumber = 1;

  int get svgNumber => _svgNumber;

  set svgNumber(int value) {
    _svgNumber = value;
    profilePicPreferences.setProfilePic(value);
    notifyListeners();
  }

  void changePic(int val) {
    _svgNumber = val;
    profilePicPreferences.setProfilePic(val);
    notifyListeners();
  }
}
```

[image: See the GIF]

### or

[watch the full video](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1--dht_RYh4QN1BN1jDH_dIjgXhz7MsI-/view?usp=sharing)

Here is the widget tree. When user tap on a profile image it updates the current. But does not save that data.
And the problem is, I have to manually save the code, in order to see the previously selected profile image. Someone please help me to save current account picture data locally.

```
class SelectProfilePicture extends StatefulWidget {
  const SelectProfilePicture({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<SelectProfilePicture> createState() => _SelectProfilePictureState();
}

class _SelectProfilePictureState extends State<SelectProfilePicture> {

  int svgNumber = 1;

  ProfilePicProvider proProvider = ProfilePicProvider();
  @override
  void initState() {
    getCurrentProfilePicture();
    super.initState();
  }

  void getCurrentProfilePicture() async {
    proProvider.svgNumber =
        await proProvider.profilePicPreferences.getProfilePicture();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    return Scaffold(
      body: Column(
        children: [
          CurrentAccountPicture(path: 'assets/svg/${proProvider.svgNumber}.svg'),  // I want update this widget using users preferences. By default it is set to 1.svg
          Center(
            child: Text(
              'Current Account Picture',
              style: style(),
            ),
          ),
          Expanded(
            child: GridView.builder(
              itemCount: 15,
              gridDelegate: const SliverGridDelegateWithFixedCrossAxisCount(
                crossAxisCount: 3,
              ),
              itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                return GestureDetector(
                  onTap: () {
                    setState(() {
                      svgNumber = index + 1;
                    });
                    proProvider.changePic(index + 1);
                  },
                  child: SvgPicture.asset('assets/svg/${index + 1}.svg'),
                );
              },
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your svgNumber is saved just fine. It's just that after reading it from storage it doesn't know to refresh the page.

Since you use a `ChangeNotifier` you could write code to listen to it.

Alternatively, I think that putting the reading in a `setState` should also solve it. So like:

```
  void getCurrentProfilePicture() async {
   
      proProvider.svgNumber =
        await proProvider.profilePicPreferences.getProfilePicture();

      setState(() {});
  
  }
```